# what should be returned for http put request if id does not exist?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am building the restful web service. For the put request, I first find the testBean with the id in the pathvariable. If it does not exist, then I create a new one. I am wondering if it is right to create a new one here, or I should throw the exception. Because id is auto increment, if I create a new TestBean, the id saved in the db is different from the one from the url path parameter.

```
@PutMapping("/Test/{id}")
   public TestBean updateTestBean(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody TestBean newTestBean) {
      return testBeanService.getTestById(id)
         .map(testBean -> {
            testBean.setBRR(newTestBean.getBRR());
            testBean.setModifiedDate(newTestBean.getModifiedDate());
            return crewsBeanService.saveTestBean(testBean);
         })
         .orElseGet(() -> {
            newTestBean.setId(id);
            return testBeanService.saveTestBean(newTestBean);
         });
   }
```

Comment: 201 Created would be a good fit, if you want to create a new entry. Use 404 if you decide not to. Do return the new object with any successful response though, so that clients can see everything that changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd always prefer to keep PUT method idempotent. Idempotency can be explained as how many times you apply a certain "operation", the result will be the same as the first time. Since REST is just a style, it's up to you, but I will always question to me if it makes sense to keep the operation as PUT or POST.

What if the client of your service is impatient and access your PUT service multiple times while the first request is being served?. You may end up creating two users. **So throwing an exception is meaningful if the ID doesn't exist**.

It can be 400 or 404, **I don't prefer 404** but prefer 400 because of the following reasons,

1) It confuses the client of your APIs if the resource is wrong or the ID they are using is wrong.
(You can always differentiate in your error response and provide meaningful information, but still, I don't prefer!)

2) By using 404,

> you're telling the user the problem could be permanent or temporary

,for instance, say your service is not properly registered with discovery server(eureka) or is crashed, the discovery server will send 404 until you fix the problem.

By using 400,

> you're asking the user to try with different input, in this case, with a different ID. This is permanent...

as you said id is auto-increment and the client cannot decide the value, so until the user fixes the problem by going back and request your POST service for a new ID, the request is "BAD" and cannot be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Single Responsibility Principle, you should have methods which are doing only one thing. So for your question, you need 2 methods for each request:

**GET** - asking the server for an object, in your case `TestBean`.

**POST** - save new objects (you don't need an id for these).

And in your front end application you could use the **GET** to ask the server if it have the requested object, and if not, maybe you can add a form which on submit will make the **POST** request with the data provided in the form fields.

Answer (score 0):

PUT should only be responsible for updating a record. If the id of your bean doesn't exist, you will have an exception on your persistence layer. You can catch that exception on your API and return one of the 400's response code, such as BAD REQUEST.

For creation you should use POST, an id should not be provided in that case

This would be the RESTful way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

`404` is the correct return code for a `PUT` to a non-existent resource, because the URL used does not address an extant resource.

Answer (score 0):

> If the Request-URI does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is capable of being defined as a new resource by the requesting user agent, the origin server can create the resource with that URI.
>
> If the server desires that the request be applied to a different URI, it MUST send a 301 (Moved Permanently) response; the user agent MAY then make its own decision regarding whether or not to redirect the request.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html